# DBEAVER Cloud Impala Connection Property Null has Invalid Value of {1}. Valid values are {2}

Tags: sql, cloudera, impala, dbeaver

```
[Cloudera][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500174) Connection Property null has invalid value of {1}. Valid values are: {2}.

IncorrectTypeException

com.cloudera.impala.dsi.exceptions.IncorrectTypeException
```

Has anyone seen this error message before when trying to connect to Cloudera Impala from DBeaver? I got this when creating the database connection.

I can't find anything on this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, check your URL Template. If you are like me, you are missing a semi-colon somewhere.